# Как в конкретной строчке файла изменить текст до символа?

Tags: c#

У меня есть файл с кодом на C. Необходимо найти там 100 строчку, это будет вызов функции. И заменить там название функции. Т.е. найти символы до открытия скобочки `(` и заменить на другое название. Как это можно адекватно прописать на C#?

Comment: С помощью регулярки, например

Comment: @АндрейNOP а если я не знаю название функции, которую я ищу. Но знаю, что она вызывается в 100 строке? Открыть файл - пройтись по строкам, и в 100 строке найти символы и заменить их?

Comment: Читай построчно и пиши в новый файл. При этом считай строки, и сотую строку обработай (отдели открывающую скобку и хвост за ней, и прилепи к новому имени функции). Ну или сразу зачитай всё построчно в массив, обработай 100-й элемент. и сбрось так же построчно в новый файл.

Comment: @Akina всё, понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Считать файл как строки (File.ReadAllLines, File.ReadAllText), выполнить необходимую обработку строк, перезаписать файл.